# Executing .jar file from command line cannot find the configuration file in the root folder

Tags: java, jar

I wrote an application which starts by reading a configuration (.ini) file and accordingly parses some xml files within a particular folder.

Everything works perfectly when I build and run my application in NetBeans. Now I wanted to run my application through command line (because that's actual requirement of my project), so I am executing the .jar file created by Netbeans to run my application.

I am executing the application as such: java -jar Application.jar.

The issue is when I run this command on command line, the application seems to not be able to find the configuration file which is in the root folder of the project. Its really odd because NetBeans runs it perfectly.

I believe the reason I am getting this exception is because to run the .jar file I am changing my directory to dist and then running the java -jar command and therefore the file is not being found . But then how do I get around this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry got it figured out. I am executing jar file from the root but adding the source in the command as well.

Sorry, you can close this thread.

Comment: You should be able to delete ??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem till I installed JRE and did NOT use stand alone.